# R Shinydashboard Showing/Hiding UI Elements based on Tab selection

Tags: r, user-interface, dynamic, tabs, shinydashboard

I am struggling with a requirement if someone can help. I have to show/hide some elements on the Dashboardsidebar based on the tabpanel selection by the user. Here is part of the UI code to give you an idea of the structure of my app. I need to show fourthoutput, fifthout and download button only on tabpPanel 2.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My App"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 350,
    fileInput(
      'file1',
      'Upload Items List',
      accept = c('text/csv',
                 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                 '.csv')
    ),
    fluidRow(column(
      width = 2,
      offset = 1,
      actionButton("goButton", "Submit")
    )),
    br(),
    br(),
    uiOutput("FirstOutput"),
    uiOutput("SecondOutput"),
    uiOutput("ThirdOutput"),
    uiOutput("FourthOutput"),
    uiOutput("FifthOutput"),

      fluidRow(column(
        width = 2,
        offset = 1,
        downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')))
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$style(
      type = "text/css",
      ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
      ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
    ),

    tabsetPanel(
      type = "tabs",

      tabPanel("1", fluidRow(box(
        plotlyOutput("pie1")
      ),
      box(
        plotlyOutput("barplot1")
      )),
      fluidRow(box(
        plotlyOutput(outputId = "barplot2")
      ))),

      tabPanel("2",
        div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll', dataTableOutput("contents"))
      )

    )
  )
)
```

thanks,
Manoj Agrawal

Comment: `?conditionalPanel`

Comment: I tried that but somehow could not get it to work with tab as conditions. I am a beginner so maybe I wasn't doing something right. Can you please give a pseudo-code or something which I might try? thanks

Comment: also take a look at the [`shinyjs`](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs) package; in particular the `show` and `hide` functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set an `id` to the `tabsetPanel` and a value to each `tabPanel`. Then you can use `input.tabsetId` in `conditionalPanel` to hide/show the button:

```
...
conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.tabs == 'show'",
  fluidRow(column(
    width = 2,
    offset = 1,
    downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'))))
),
...

...
tabsetPanel( id="tabs",
...
tabPanel("1", value="show",
...
tabPanel("2", value="hide",
...
```