# Adding an Interactive Menu based on SelectInput in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

the given script creates the attached snapshot.It is a table created using DT package in R. I want to make the menu above the table such that by selecting an input "A" in the first SelectInput, I get the second selectInput with two sliders, while selecting "B" in the first SelectInput, I should get only the second SelectInput and no sliders. There is no change needed on the table iris. Please help and Thanks.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

#Declaring the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Interactive Menu"),

# Create a new Row in the UI for selectInputs
fluidRow(
column(3,
     selectInput("names",
                 "Customer:",
                 c("A","B"))
)),
fluidRow(

column(4,
       selectInput("names",
                   "Customer:",
                   c(as.character(iris$Species)))
),
column(4,
       sliderInput("slide", "Select the slider one",
                   min = 75, max = 100,
                   value = 75, step = 5)

),
column(4,

       sliderInput("city", "Select the slider two",
                   min = 60, max = 100,
                   value = 60, step = 10)
)),

# Create a new row for the table.
fluidRow(
DT::dataTableOutput("table1")
)
)
#Declaring the Server
server <- function(input, output) {

# Filter data based on selections
output$table1 <- renderDataTable({

datatable(iris, options = list(
  searching = FALSE,
  pageLength = 5,
  lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20)
))
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: iris_capture]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R Shinydashboard Showing/Hiding UI Elements based on Tab selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39987908/r-shinydashboard-showing-hiding-ui-elements-based-on-tab-selection)

Comment: Hi Hardik, Thanks, I have worked on this functionality, my question is, that can we implement the selectInput with conditional panel in the same way like the tabset conditional panel that this links says,also, if you have a working example, kindly share.

Comment: You could either use `conditionalPanel` or `uiOutput` with `renderUI`.

Comment: I want to add multiple selectInputs and sliders using conditioalPanel, do you happen to have a good link for a working example?

Comment: Thank you so much SBista and Hardik for your help.

Comment: You could look into [shiny reference page from RStudio](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html)

Comment: Hi SBista, please help with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783181/sliderinput-issue-with-table-in-r-shiny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your working example with the code you provided and the output you asked :

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

#Declaring the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Interactive Menu"),

  # Create a new Row in the UI for selectInputs
    fluidRow(
      column(4,
      selectInput("names",
                  "Customer:",
                  c("A","B")))
      )
    ,
  fluidRow(
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.names == 'A'",
      column(4,
             selectInput("names",
                         "Customer:",
                         c(as.character(iris$Species)))
             ),
      column(4,
             sliderInput("slide", "Select the slider one",
                         min = 75, max = 100,
                         value = 75, step = 5)),
      column(4,
             sliderInput("city", "Select the slider two",
                         min = 60, max = 100,
                         value = 60, step = 10)
      )
      ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.names == 'B'",
    column(4,
           selectInput("names",
                       "Customer:",
                       c(as.character(iris$Species)))
           ))
    ),

  # Create a new row for the table.
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table1")
  )
)
#Declaring the Server
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Filter data based on selections
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({

    datatable(iris, options = list(
      searching = FALSE,
      pageLength = 5,
      lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20)
    ))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]

As stated in the comments, the trick is to use `conditionalPanel`.

Comment: Please help with this link                                                    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783181/sliderinput-issue-with-table-in-r-shiny

Comment: please help me with this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154749/changing-the-width-height-and-alignment-of-the-shiny-widgets-in-r?noredirect=1#comment81263002_47154749

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple widgets like so:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    selectInput('data', 'Data', c('mtcars', 'iris')),
    uiOutput('columns')
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    output$columns <- renderUI({
      mydata <- get(input$data)
      tagList(
      selectInput('columns2', 'Columns', names(mydata)),
      selectInput('columns3', 'Columns 2', names(mydata)))
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Thanks, great help.

Comment: Hey, I need a little help with this post if you can help me, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766286/slider-not-giving-proper-value-when-pointed-at-100-in-r-shiny-table